# How to change sqljdbc.jar file to sqljdbc4.jar in JDBC provider?

Tags: sql-server-2005, websphere-7

How to change sqljdbc.jar file to sqljdbc4.jar in JDBC provider in  WebSphere Appliction Server? Because I'm putting that file in application, but where should I put it in Websphere to be visible by classpath in jdbc provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put sqljdbc4.jar with your application. Create directory on file system where WebSphere Application Server is installed e.g. `/drivers/mssql`. Put your sqljdbc4.jar there.

Create new JDBC provider for MSSQL Server, if you don't already have one. If you have, can see its details in console via `Resouces > JDBC > JDBC Providers`. In the provider classpath you should see entry like this: `${MICROSOFT_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/sqljdbc4.jar`. If you see sqljdbc.jar you might created DataDirect driver provider instead of MS SQL Server provider (in that case create new provider).

Then check your `${MICROSOFT_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}` variable via `Environment > WebSphere variables` and edit this variable to point to your `/drivers/mssql` folder.

If you had incorrect provider, you will need to recreate DataSources under your new provider.

Comment: i created DataDirect driver provider instead of MS SQL Server provider bt also in class path seeing sqljdbc.jar what i do ?

Comment: Thanks Gas-- but i don't give instead of MS SQL Server provider to DataDirect driver provide what happend please tell me .

Comment: Use the `MS SQL Server provider`, not the DataDirect. You should have sqljdbc4.jar in the provider classpath definition there.